# Creating an alias for a function type

Tags: angularjs, typescript, type-alias

In an application I'm working on, I had to translate an AngularJS filter and directive into TypeScript v2.4.

I found a pattern in what I had to do to get the directive to work with AngularJS's `$filter` service - I needed to use the `$filter<\T>('???')(value)` overload in order to apply a custom telephone format filter to the directive.

Here's the translated directive's link function:

```
link: (scope: any, elem: any, attrs: any, ctrl: angular.INgModelController) => {
    const mask: string = '(999) 999-9999';

    $(elem).mask(mask);

    const nonDigitCharacers: RegExp = /[^0-9]/g;

    elem.on('keydown', (evt: any) => {
        scope.$evalAsync(elem.triggerHandler.bind(elem, 'change', evt));
    });

    ctrl.$validators.minLength = (modelValue: string, viewValue: string) => {
        let minLength: number = 0;
        if (attrs.minlength)
            minLength = parseInt(attrs.minlength);

        let stringValue: string = $filter<(input: string) => string>('tel')(modelValue);
        let longEnough: boolean = stringValue.length > minLength;

        // If value not required, and nothing is entered, the value is valid.
        if (!attrs.required && stringValue.length === 0)
            return true;

        // If value is required, and nothing is entered, this value is 'valid'.
        // The point of this code is to not interfere with a required attribute!
        if (attrs.required && stringValue.length === 0)
            return true;

        return longEnough;
    };

    ctrl.$parsers.unshift((viewValue: string) => {
        let digitsOnly: string = viewValue.replace(nonDigitCharacers, '');
        return digitsOnly;
    });

    ctrl.$formatters.push((value: string) => {
        return $filter<(input: string) => string>('tel')(value);
    });
}
```

...The thing I'm noticing is that I have to do `$filter<(input: string) => string>('tel')(value)` twice in this, otherwise it won't compile to JavaScript.  That seems wasteful, however - what I'd like to do is create what a C# developer might recognize as a delegate name, or what other languages might call a type alias, as such:

```
// It wouldn't be an interface, but I don't really know what it *would* be...
export interface IFilterFunctionType = (input: string) => string;

// Using it...
return $filter<IFilterFunctionType>('tel')('1234567890');
```

**Question:** In what way, if there is any, could I create an alias of a function type in TypeScript 2.4?

Comment: Are you not aware of [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) in TypeScript?

Comment: I wasn't.  If you can find a better way to word that response, though, I'd take it as an answer.  There's plenty I don't know about TypeScript, if that wasn't obvious.

Comment: Sure thing, just did.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does indeed have [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)!  As you suspect, you do not declare it as an `interface`.  Instead, you just need to declare it as a `type`, using essentially the same syntax you used (assignment with `=`):

```
export type IFilterFunctionType = (input: string) => string;  
return $filter<IFilterFunctionType>('tel')('1234567890');
```

I recommend taking a read-through of the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) if you have the time, as it contains other goodies you might find useful when programming in TypeScript.  Hope that helps.